# Are "what's new in <tech-of-choice> 3.x" questions ok?

Tags: discussion

Sometimes my questions are marked as invalid, and the rules shift over time, so I rather ask:

Can I ask about what's new in major version of some technology when it's not clear from it's own documentation?

If not, why?

*Edit:*

It seems that some people do not understand the "it's not clear from it's own documentation" part of this question. So let me explain.

It is not written in the documentation. The project has moved to the Apache Foundation, and underwent architectural changes, but the tutorials remain the same. This is what the documentation says about the new major:

> The thought too much to bear as he approached his realization of The
>   TinkerPop. The closer he got, the more his world dissolved — west is
>   right, around is straight, and form nothing more than nothing. With
>   each step towards The TinkerPop, less and less of his world, but
>   perhaps because more and more of all the other worlds made possible.
>   Everything is everything in The TinkerPop, and when the dust settled,
>   Gremlin emerged Gremlitron. It was time to realize that all that he
>   realized was just a realization and that all realized realizations are
>   just as real. For The TinkerPop is and is not — The TinkerPop.

There's a presentation called What's new in version 3 but I can only see slideshow, which contains mostly screenshots of a console, showing some new commands, but without the speach, one can't tell what they are for. Also there are some illustrations but again, withoud sound, they are too abstract.

It seems to me that people here on SO developed some stereotypes and just think in those stereotypes and don't consider corner cases.
Can anyone tell me for real why it's not good to ask on stackowerflow what's new in Tinkerpop 3?

Comment: I'm hesitant to say "yes"...especially considering that it'd be a question with a bunch of answers that essentially list what the documentation would be saying.

Comment: It would be interesting to know if this could fit the new "documentation" feature we're working on.

Comment: @gnat:  I don't think that dupe target is suitable.  That one assumes that the OP understands that Stack Overflow isn't the correct site, whereas this one is trying to clarify this fact.

Comment: @Makoto - as I said. It is not clear from the documentation.

Comment: I am not quite sure why even this question is downvoted? Well, downvote at will instead of providing an answer. Thanks a lot. –

Comment: People downvote because they disagree.  How hard is that to understand?  And we aren't required to provide an alternative if we disagree with something.

Comment: So. People read your question,  go "I sympathize. Still doesn't make it on topic for stack, so I disagree. I'm on meta, where disagreement can be exoressed via downvotes. from what is already said in comments I don't need to add my thoughts, I see someone else already did". So why is downvote NOT appropriate?

Answer (score 8):

For the most part, they would be off topic since you're looking for someone to find you an off-site resource (a press release or document page)

That being said, it would be possible to write an on-topic question... For example

> I've just upgraded my Foo from version x to version y and I've noticed
>   that my results for Bar have changed
>
> Using the following code I get z in version x and z+1 in version y
>
> ```
> enter code here
> ```
>
> What changed that made my results different?

Its clear/precise, shows research effort, and is potentially useful to others.

If you were just looking for a list then that is more something that you would want to contact the owners of the library about.

Comment: Not really. I am not asking someone to search outside the documentation, I have done that. It seems that only someone already using that version can really answer.

Comment: Your example question would be downvoted and closed as too specific.

Comment: @OndraŽižka - I'd argue that it can only be answered by someone that contributed to the project that can answer, I can't think of a single framework I use where I'd be able to say everything that has been changed (without docs)

Comment: @OndraŽižka - It definitely wouldn't be downvoted by me, perhaps I'm biased but as I show underneath my example, it meets all three criteria for an upvote. There isn't a close reason any more for a too specific question

Comment: I wouldn't dv or vtc that question either. .. and "too specific" isn't valid to close a question....